# Online Pdf to Image convertor

Tags: android

I am using some application on Android to read Online PDF. I would like to take thumbnail images of all the pages in that online PDF to my application. Any suggestion on this or any other API?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to do it is to take a bunch of screenshots. On most android devices, you press the **down volume button and the power button at the same time.**

Afterwards, you can either upload those pictures onto evernote, or plug in a usb to your computer and you can covert those images using photoshop or other related software.

Hope this somewhat helps. 
Cheers!